# SAS how to sum even if there are missing value?

Tags: sas, missing-data, calculus

This is my data, let me call it 'time'.

```
 VAR1              VAR2              VAR3             VAR4
 02NOV14:10:23:00 02NOV14:10:38:00 02NOV14:10:38:00   
 02NOV14:12:52:00 02NOV14:13:05:00     
 02NOV14:18:57:00 02NOV14:19:14:00 02NOV14:19:14:00 02NOV14:19:14:00 
 03NOV14:10:13:00 03NOV14:10:13:00     
 03NOV14:16:33:00 03NOV14:17:29:00 03NOV14:17:29:00   
 03NOV14:12:35:00 03NOV14:12:40:00 03NOV14:12:40:00   
 03NOV14:13:26:00 03NOV14:13:59:00 03NOV14:13:59:00   
 03NOV14:14:34:00 03NOV14:14:41:00 03NOV14:14:41:00   
 03NOV14:15:12:00 03NOV14:15:14:00 03NOV14:15:14:00   
 03NOV14:15:48:00 03NOV14:16:18:00 03NOV14:16:18:00   
 03NOV14:15:51:00 06NOV14:14:46:00 06NOV14:14:46:00    
 07NOV14:11:35:00 07NOV14:12:15:00 07NOV14:12:15:00   
 07NOV14:12:32:00 07NOV14:14:34:00 07NOV14:14:34:00 07NOV14:14:34:00 
 07NOV14:12:18:00 07NOV14:12:19:00 07NOV14:12:19:00 07NOV14:12:19:00 
 08NOV14:20:57:00 08NOV14:21:03:00 08NOV14:21:03:00
```

and I want to create new variable

```
VAR5 = VAR2 - VAR1;
VAR6 = VAR3 - VAR1;
VAR7 = VAR4 - VAR1;
```

I use this code

```
data time;
set time;
VAR5 = VAR2 - VAR1;
VAR6 = VAR3 - VAR1;
VAR7 = VAR4 - VAR1;
run;
```

and when I print,  VAR6 and VAR7 are empty. I guess because of missing values in VAR 3 and in VAR4 SAS doesn't calculate VAR6 and VAR7. How to get values for them when I have data?
Can someone help me?

times to times i have values for VAR3 and VAR4 and times to times I don't. So i want to have value for  VAR 6 AND VAR7 when it's possible. for example for the first observation I can have VAR5 VAR6 but not VAR7 because there are no values for the second observation I can only have VAR5 ,for the third one normally I will get VAR5 VAR6 and VAR7.

Comment: Your code references a dataset called `data`, which you haven't mentioned earlier in the question.

Comment: I can't see why var6 or var7 would be missing, unless var3, var4 or var1 were missing.

Comment: What value do you want for var6/var7 when var3/var4 is missing?

Comment: Googled, "sas missing values sum".  Gave me: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000989183.htm

Comment: You're not sufficiently explaining what you want to happen here.  Show an example "WANT" dataset with the values you actually want to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Updated the code accordingly.
Not missing function will make sure calculations are happening only when the arguments are not missing.

```
data time;
set time;
if not missing(var1) then do;
if not missing(Var2) then VAR5 = VAR2 - VAR1;
if not missing(Var3) then VAR6 = VAR3 - VAR1;
if not missing(Var4) then VAR7 = VAR4 - VAR1;
end;
run;
```

Comment: I don't want a response when there is no value. I want a response only when I have values.

Comment: BTW if you do not want a response then your code should do the needful because when one of the arguments is missing and when you will use that in the calculations, the end result will be a missing value. Now i am a bit confused on what are you looking for?

Comment: I hope you know that in SAS the missing numeric value is represented by "." (a dot). So you are not gonna get a complete blank.

Comment: That is a blank/nothing/No response etc ... it is represented by a "." (dot) in SAS because it is numeric, had it been character in nature you would have got ""(complete blank). I hope you got it now.